# how to get request object in django unit testing?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I have a function as

```
def getEvents(eid, request):
    ......
```

Now I want to write unit test for the above function separately (without calling the view). 
So how should I call the above in `TestCase`. Is it possible to create request ?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

See [this solution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory):

```
from django.utils import unittest
from django.test.client import RequestFactory

class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_details(self):
        # Create an instance of a GET request.
        request = self.factory.get('/customer/details')

        # Test my_view() as if it were deployed at /customer/details
        response = my_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: This code has actually been included in Django since version 1.3.

Comment: If I see this correctly, that fake request from the factory doesn't get filtered through middleware(s).

Comment: I was really confused by Roseman's comment, but the answer used to include code for `RequestFactory`.  Nothing currently includes it in the `TestCase`, so you still have to import it as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 52):

If you are using django test client (`from django.test.client import Client`) you can access request from response object like this:

```
from django.test.client import Client

client = Client()
response = client.get(some_url)
request = response.wsgi_request
```

or if you are using `django.TestCase`(`from django.test import TestCase, SimpleTestCase, TransactionTestCase`) you can access client instance in any testcase just by typing `self.client`:

```
response = self.client.get(some_url)
request = response.wsgi_request
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/4.0/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory)  to create a dummy request.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `def getEvents(request, eid)` right?

With Django unittest, you can use the `from django.test.client import Client` to make request.

See here: [Test Client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client)

@Secator's answer is prefect as it creates a mock object which is really preferred for a really good unittest. But depending on your purpose, it might be easier to just use Django's test tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django test client

```
from django.test import Client
c = Client()
response = c.post('/login/', {'username': 'john', 'password': 'smith'})
response.status_code
response = c.get('/customer/details/')
response.content
```

for more details
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example