# Debuging a request in Django through "./manage.py shell"

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a way to get the `request` in the Django shell (`./manage.py shell`)?

Here is an example on how I currently do it which will make the question more clear.

---

File: views.py

```
import ipdb

def index(request):
    ipdb.set_trace()
    #method code ...
    return render(...)
```

What `ipdb.set_trace()` does is open a ipython shell and gives me access to all the objects available at that point in the method `index` including the `request`.

For example, i can check `request.user.is_anonymous()`.

However, I can't convert that to unit tests because the way of getting there is to "human depended", so I'm looking for a way to achieve the similar result purely from the Django shell.

Comment: You will have to build your own request object like in a django unit test. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277748/how-to-get-request-object-in-django-unit-testing